# swapping of field names in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two fields **field1** and **field2** in an index of an elasticsearch

I need to rename **field1** to **field2**
and also i want to rename **field2** to **field1**

This is how my current mapping looks and I had indexed many documents for this mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "field2" : {
        "type" : "completion"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And i need the following mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "completion"
      },
      "field2" : {
        "type" : "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any possibiltiy that i can rename fields and do reindexing ?

I am using elasticsearch version 7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that using the [update-by-query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/docs-update-by-query.html), like this:

```
POST index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "def tmp1 = ctx._source.field2; ctx._source.field2 = ctx._source.field1; ctx._source.field1 = tmp1;",
    "lang": "painless"
  }
}
```